# Can I write to a specific index of a List, if I know no other thread will access that index without a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, locking

I have 4 threads that each have their own loop and they access a List that contains a delta time for each thread. Since there are 4 threads in this example, there will be 4 items in the List. Can these threads change the value of their assigned index (example: thread 0 - index 0 of List) without locks since I know no other thread will write to that index, or if I just need to use locks for this.

I have already implemented this and it does not seem to effect the other values or corrupt the list, but I want to make sure.

```
int threadCount = 4;
bool run = true;
List<double> lastDeltaTime = new List<double>();
private List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();

void InitializeThreads()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
          {
            int tempName = i;
            Thread tempThread = new Thread(() => ThreadLoop(tempName));
            threadList.Add(tempThread);

            lastDeltaTime.Add(0);
          }

     for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            threadList[i].Start();
        }
}

void ThreadLoop(int threadName)
{
     double lastTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
     while(run)
     {
          double currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
          double deltaTime = ((currentTime - lastTime) / 10000000) * timescale;
          lastDeltaTime[threadName] = deltaTime; //line setting deltaTime
          //do work

          //end work
          lastTime = currentTime;
     }
}
```

Comment: If no additions or removals are being made, **and** they only access **their** index, then you don't need locks.  Why use a List then, though?  Why not four different variables?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I do not use 4 defined variables because the goal is for the system to scale to however many threads the user wants. So if they want 8 threads, I need to dynamically create a deltaTime variable for each thread.

Comment: Surely you can just try this out and then ask a more specific question if you run into some problem.

Comment: @RufusL I have already done it and it works, but it is imperative the data keeps its integrity. That is why I am double checking.

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't quite understand the question then. Why would you need locks at all if each thread is writing to a different index? Are you asking if two threads writing to the same index could set a partial (or corrupt) value to that item? Perhaps a small sample would illustrate the issue better, but in general you should consider using a thread-safe collection instead of a `List<T>` if you're accessing it from multiple threads.

Comment: @RufusL You seem to have answered my question with "Why would you need locks at all if each thread is writing to a different index?". Thread 0 will write to only index 0, and Thread 1 will only write to index 1. Never will they touch the other. I just could not find confirmation anywhere online that this was ok to do, hence my post.

Comment: Use a **CLASS** that encapsulates both the thread and the deltaTime.  Now use a List<YourClass>. Done; scalable.

Comment: Whether the code works properly or not depends a lot on the specifics of what you're doing.  As you have not provided specifics, it's not possible to say whether what you're doing will work on not.  Details *matter*, especially in multithreaded code where the difference between working or broken code is so subtle.

Comment: @Servy I added an example, if you could take a look at it that would be helpful.

Comment: @RufusL If you could take a peek at my code example I just added I would appreciate another set of eyes on it.

Comment: @RufusL - "try this out" is the one thing that doesn't work very well for achieving thread safety. Many symptoms are hard to rerproduce.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Fair point. Also, I commented prematurely because I missed the sentence where the OP stated they had already tried it.

Comment: @DevinNorthern - it probably is safe but the docs for `List<>` won't give that to you in writing. The (absolutely) safe thing to do is to use an array.

Comment: You might want to make `lastDeltaTime` an array instead of a List.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That makes sense, It all comes down to can you be disciplined to not add or remove from the collection, right?.  So use an array and don't have the worry?

Comment: @RufusL I will do that just to have the added security of not being able to change the size of it.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Great idea with the Class. I may do that for the ease of reading the data structure better.

Comment: @DevinNorthern - no, discipline is not enough. The List is not documented as thread-safe and the setter (as used in `a[i] = x;`) _might_ in a future release decide to do some housekeeping. And then blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Information Learned:

- It is okay to write to an index location of a list with a Thread without a lock ONLY if you can ensure no other Thread will also try to write to the same index, and that the list will remain the same size.
- Use an array if you can ensure that no other Thread will try to write to the same index location
- Use a Class that contains the Thread and the variable, then make a list of the Class (Not Tested by me as of yet)
- Otherwise ... use a lock

Comment: Write this as an edit to the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: You also need to be careful if some other thread is *reading* the value, since it might read from memory that is only partially updated (DateTime is not small enough to fit within an atomic memory read/write). If no other thread is reading the value, then I would suggest the variable should be held as a local variable declared within `ThreadLoop`. That way you'd be completely safe since each thread has its own stack and therefore its own local variables.

Answer (score -3):

That's not safe to do at all.  You're adding items to the list while accessing other items, which is a problem if that addition results in resizing the backing array.  You can end up accessing items while the list is in the middle of a resize, which can break in any number of different ways.

Comment: Where am I creating new items while accessing? The List is set up prior to the Threads Starting and stay the same size after that.

Comment: @DevinNorthern If you intend the list to never be mutated then why have a mutable list exposed in the first place.  If you never want the size to ever change, *don't use a structure whose size can change* and break all of your code.

Comment: make sense, I will use an array. Thank you for your feedback.